# Cannot append string in a function

Tags: php, append

I wrote this in PHP:

```
<?php   
    function glueString($str1, $str2)   {
            $tempstr = $str1 + $str2;
            return $tempstr;
    }   
    $s1 = 'this is a line.';
    $s2 = 'this is another line.';
    echo $s1.'<br/>'.$s2.'<br/>'.glueString($s1, $s2);
    
?>
```

I got this error:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\test.php on line 4
>
> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\test.php on line 4

```
this is a line.
this is another line.
0
```

Comment: Like in your `echo $s1.'<br/>'.$s2.` you concatenate using `.`, not `+`

Comment: Beyond that, `glueString` is a pointless function. You may as well just say `$foo . $bar` directly in the caller like you're doing and save a lot of typing and confusion about what `glueString` does (it's a big wrapper on `.`, essentially).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.` to concatenate a string. `+` is used to concatenate string in javascript. So you are mixing javascript and PHP here. `+` is used to add two integer values

```
function glueString($str1, $str2)   {
    $tempstr = $str1.' '.$str2;
    return $tempstr;
}

$s1 = 'this is a line.';
$s2 = 'this is another line.';
echo $s1.'<br/>'.$s2.'<br/>'.glueString($s1, $s2);
```